# Facebook Deep Link Tester Works, Ad Doesn't

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Pretty straightforward situation: I'm doing deferred deep links for Facebook ads and have successfully tested them via the Deep Link Tester [found here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/) (to be clear I do also select "Send Deferred".) However, putting the app into production, even though I am certain that the app has received new launches via ads, the deferred deep link code returns null. Testing it via an Ad Preview is broken as well.

I'm not getting any errors logged from the Facebook SDK and I have confirmed that both the application id and the client token exist when I make the fetchDeferredAppLinkData call.

I've exhausted StackOverflow/Facebook/Google for possible solutions or reasons why there would be a difference between the Deep Link Tester and the actual ad, but have 0 clue. Any direction or thoughts would be really helpful, thanks so much!

For reference, here's the code I'm using to handle the deferred deep link:

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                    if(appLinkData != null) {
                         //Handling link
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

**EDIT:** It looks like we're now getting the fetchDeferredAppLinkData to return values in production, this was after saving the client token in onCreate. However, Ad Previews still don't work in testing; is this by design? Are Ad Previews not intended to be fully-functional and thus shouldn't be used for this purpose?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your solution for production? What does it mean: "this was after saving the client token in onCreate"? I have the same issue